# 'Missing Region error' with AWS amplify Storage and React frontend

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```js
import './App.css';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import { AmplifySignOut, withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';


Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

async function get_photo(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("Finding photo");
  //Storage.get('ASSET_2.jpg').then(result => console.log(result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
  Storage.get('ASSET_2.jpg');
  console.log("Image present");
  
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
       <AmplifySignOut />
       <button onClick = {get_photo}>Get the photo</button>
       <h2>App content</h2>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

While trying to fetch the image from the AWS S3 bucket using the AWS Amplify Storage.get method, I am getting the error, Region Missing, even though, aws-exports file has the region info. Can someone help me sort this out?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mENiN.png)

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't match any part of the screenshot - can you please share the contents of the file where the error happens?

Comment: The files in the error image are a part of the amplify storage configuration, and not present in my app folder.

Comment: The  error occurs in the line where, it says Storage.get(.......);

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(awsconfig);`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug with Amplify. It happens only in the Storage.get() method for me.

I ended up forcing the re-configuration of the region, by including this line, in the get method:

```
Storage.configure({ region: "eu-west-1" });
```

Make sure to include your own region.